Move domain without affecting email service
I am helping a friend set up a website for his business. He purchased a Microsoft 365 Business plan, which includes a custom business email (you@yourbusiness.com) and  domain (yourbusiness.com) registered through GoDaddy.
We are going to host the website on FastComet.
The move should not affect Microsoft 365.
Will a move of domain affect the email service?
Will Microsoft 365 continue working?
Can we continue without losing any received emails?
Am I right to assume that nothing will affect the email service and Microsoft 365 as long as the MX records stay the same?
I have been told that to be able to host the website on FastComet, I need to update the name servers to FastComet. Currently it is  Microsoft nameservers.
Do they need to have Microsoft nameservers to make it work with the email?
What are the necessary steps I need to make everything work as expected?

Please help your friend by advising him to go to a professional.

From the sound of it, you're not moving the domain, you're setting up a website for the domain. Create the appropriate DNS records for the website and leave all the other DNS records alone.

Also, I have been told that to be able to host the website on
FastComet I need to update the naming servers to point to FastComet's
own.

That isn't necessary nor required. If FastComet is telling you that it is required then tell them you don't want to do that. If they insist that it's required then find a new website hosting company.

So, I don't need to move my domain to have my website up and running on FastComet? How does that work? Also, I'm quite unfamiliar with DNS, how do I know how to set that up properly?
Alright, so the nameservers on Fastcomet should be pointed to Microsoft's own?
